# Casting char to int reference in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

[UPDATE: Yakk pretty much answered my question, but I'm updating the question for clarity. I have one other question, that I mention at the end.]

I am trying to write a serialization function, as a part of which, I need to convert char to int, and leave other types unchanged. I have written the following code:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
template<typename T1>
struct return_type {typedef T1 type;};
template<>
struct return_type<char> {typedef int type;};

template<typename T1>
typename return_type<T1>::type &type_transform(T1 &&t) 
{
    //If writing/reading char, cast it to int 
    return static_cast<typename return_type<T1>::type &>(t);
} 

template<typename T1>
typename return_type<T1>::type &type_transform(T1 &t) 
{
    //If writing/reading char, cast it to int 
    return static_cast<typename return_type<T1>::type &>(t);
} 

char fn()
{
    return '\n';
}

main()
{

    ofstream ofs("serialized.txt");
    //        ofs<<type_transform(fn()); error, should write 10
    ofs.close();
    ifstream ifs("serialized.txt");
    //        ifs>>type_transform(b);    error, should read newline back

}
```

I get an error:

`invalid static_cast from type ‘char’ to type ‘return_type<char>::type& {aka int&}’`

Questions:

1. How can I make this work?
2. How can I avoid rewriting the template specialization for lvalue and rvalue references?

Comment: 1. Please post actual code of how you could call it. What's `variable`, what's `func()`? 2. Post full compiler error.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `boost::lexical_cast`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind a reference to `int` to a `char`.

If you want to read something as another type, do a bit more work:

```
template<class T>
struct io_storage {
  T& t;
  io_storage(io_storage&&)=default;
  io_storage(T& tin):t(tin) {}
};
template<class T, class=void, class storage=io_storage<T>>
struct io_read_helper_t:storage {
  friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& i, io_read_helper_t x ) {
    return i >> x.t;
  }
  using storage::storage;
};
template<class T, class=void, class storage=io_storage<T>>
struct io_write_helper_t:storage {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, io_write_helper_t x ) {
    return o << x.t;
  }
  using storage::storage;
};
template<class T, class impl=io_write_helper_t<T, void, io_read_helper_t<T>>>
struct io_helper_t : impl {
  using impl::impl;
};

template<class T>
io_helper_t<T> io_helper( T& t ) { return {t}; }
template<class T>
io_write_helper_t<const T> io_helper( T const& t ) { return {t}; }
template<class T>
io_write_helper_t<const T> io_helper( T&& t ) { return {t}; }

template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class T>
struct io_type_as {};
template<> struct io_type_as<char>{ using type=int; };

template<class T>
using io_type_as_t=typename io_type_as<typename std::remove_const<T>::type>::type;

template<class T, class storage>
struct io_read_helper_t<T, void_t<io_type_as_t<T>>, storage>:storage {
  using X=io_type_as_t<T>;
  friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& i, io_read_helper_t x ) {
    X tmp;
    auto& r = i >> io_helper(tmp);
    x.t = std::move(tmp);
    return r;
  }
  using storage::storage;
};
template<class T, class storage>
struct io_write_helper_t<T, void_t<io_type_as_t<T>>, storage>:storage {
  using X=io_type_as_t<T>;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, io_write_helper_t x )
  {
    return o << io_helper(X(x.t));
  }
  using storage::storage;
};
```

now, if you define `io_type_as<X>::type` to be `Y`, `iohelper(x)` will automatically read/write as type `Y`, and be assigned before/after as needed.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25cb255f5ba53417)

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question, and added one at the end. Could you please explain how we could avoid writing separate specializations for function templates with lvalue references and rvalue references?

Comment: @user2308211 split read and write io helpers.  Made `io_helper` function determine which to use based on r/l/constness of argument.  Code refuses to read into an rvalue (which is usually the sign of a bug: I'd advise against changing that.  Make reading into rvalues explicit), but will write from one.

Comment: @user2308211 and typos fixed, live example added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-think your design.

`static_cast` will not allow casting `char` or `char&` to `int&`. That's what's going to happen in the following call:

```
f1>>type_transform(variable);
```

if `variable` is of type `char`.